# Clean URLs not working, I can't log in to Admin Panel

Tags: .htaccess, uri

I just moved my drupal website to another host. But I am unable to login as `mysite.com/user`. It gives me a `404 not found` error which means clean urls are not working afaik.

So, I checked PHP configuration with `phpinfo();` and there is `"mod_rewrite"` visible in `"loaded modules"` section.

Anyway, I wanted to disable clean urls, however if I try to login as `mysite.com/?q=user`, it redirects to `mysite.com/user` and it is giving `404 not found` error again.

So I kinda have no way to login to my website to update URL aliases. I have renamed my `.htaccess` file to disable it, result did not change.

I have updated this line:

```
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

to this line:

```
  # RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Still, nothing changes. Since I can't control the web server, all I have is FTP and MySQL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this line to your settings.php file and it would allow you to login

```
$conf = array( 'clean_url' => 0,);
```

Another method is to find the .htaccess file in D7 root, and open it,
find the `"# RewriteBase /drupal"` in codes, delete the `"#"`, change the "drupal" to your file's name: my file is "blog",
"RewriteBase /blog" - the end change to this.

Comment: Hi, thank you, the configuration array has solved my problem. I mean, at least I have disabled Clean URLs. I can go like this, but I'll try to use Clean URLs now. My website is running under no folder, even not something like httpdocs. So I update the line as "RewriteBase /" but no, nothing changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Why you not try first to disable the clean urls from site using something like

```
$conf = array(
   'clean_url' => 0,
);
```

in settings.php, or maybe searching in the database with phpmyadmin the variable clean_url. Also, take a look to this post https://drupal.org/node/256410